# What happens to Zookeeper if the DNS goes down?

Tags: dns, apache-zookeeper

I'm studying Zookeeper and how one of its most prized aspects is high availability. Recently, our internal DNS was having issues, that negatively affected Zookeeper, and other services depending on it.

I don't know much about DNS, static/dynamic ip's, DNS caching, and lookups, but what would be best practices to deal with Zookeeper and DNS issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A running Zookeeper cluster shouldn't be affected by DNS issues. Each server instance in the cluster is a JVM process. JVM caches DNS entries forever, or until restarted. Once Zookeeper server nodes are up and in the cluster, they should not be using DNS anymore. In theory you could configure your Java security options to not cache DNS forever, but this is not a default setup in case of ZK.

There could be issues during server startup. If a Zookeeper server instance cannot resolve names for other nodes in the cluster, it will refuse to serve request. Since cluster configuration is often small and mostly static, you can use IP endpoints directly in your config and avoid any possible issues.

If you have Java clients, the same DNS caching reasoning applies to them.

It is possible that during a DNS outage some clients might not be able to resolve Zookeeper endpoints. This is technically not a violation of Zookeeper's high availability property. The Zookeeper service is still available, but cannot be reached because something else on the critical path of your system failed. Zookeeper doesn't protect from that.

Comment: Thank you for the info! Do you by any chance have some resources about DNS, caching, etc? All I've come across are some huge books.

Comment: Sorry, nothing specific comes to mind at the moment. I am certain there are nice articles exploring various parts of DNS from the perspective of HA systems, Java security options, or cloud architectures. I would skip huge books until you have a general idea of your use cases and needs.

Comment: Thank you again. If you mind one more question, I read some use dynamic ip addresses for their zookeeper cluster, because it allows flexibility in replacing machines(since some cloud services go down quite often), or switching them around. And each node would expire its DNS cache every few minutes or so to get the latest dynamic ip address change. I suppose you would not be in favor of this sort of trade off?

Comment: I don't know. If you are in a dynamic cloud environment, you still have to consider if you want your zookeeper cluster to be reconfigured without control. In any case, if you have a proper cluster of 5 nodes, rolling restarts should not be a problem. Also, from version 3.5.0, you can use dynamic reconfiguration which is useful in this type of situations: http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperReconfig.html

Answer (score 2):

In JDK 6 and greater DNS caching behavior is dependent on the security manager being set.  DNS entries are only cached for 30s if a security manager is not set according to this page:

http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com/2011/03/java-dns-cache-reference-guide.html

The official documentation for JDK7 (which we're using to run zookeeper) is here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html

We recently suffered an issue with zookeeper that we're still going through, but it is clear that it is running with a 30s DNS cache (no respect for TTL).  Compiling the below and running it with the same jvm args used to run zookeper will show you the current settings:

```
public class DNSTTL {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window.
    System.out.println("DEFAULT DNS TTL: "+sun.net.InetAddressCachePolicy.get());
    }
}
```

Our result:
  DEFAULT DNS TTL: 30

I can't say definitely yet if DNS was the cause of our zookeeper cluster going down (losing leader), but it's the prime suspect at this point

Comment: Thank you for the info! Was it in fact DNS issues that caused zookeeper to go down?